# Why won't the function break out of this loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I'm not sure why, but the function that I'm using for another program won't break out of the "while" loop when it gets to the FileNotFoundError exception.

```
import os
def delete_file(file_to_delete):
    try:
        os.remove(file_to_delete)
        print('file removed: ', file_to_delete)
        result = True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error. File not found.")
        result = False
        while result == False:
            if result == True: break
            input("Please enter a valid filename: ")
        os.remove(file_to_delete)
    return result
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot. It's python.

Comment: When do you expect `result` to change?

Comment: That code is not valid python. Please post a proper [mcve]

Comment: Right.  `result` never changes.  This logic is confused.  If the file is not found, why would you want to delete it?

Comment: You forgot to check if the file is valid and change the value of `result` accordingly.

Comment: Okay. I edited the question to include the whole function.

Comment: @MedoPaw Alright. How do I make it so it changes? I ask since I had it so it would be below the input prompt "Please enter a valid filename: ", but it still wouldn't break out of the while loop.

Comment: @JakTheHero `file = input("Please enter a valid filename: ")` and then `result = os.path.isfile(filepath)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead, remove the while loop and change your logic for it to work -

```
import os
def delete_file(file_to_delete):
    result = False
    while result == False:
        try:
            os.remove(file_to_delete)
            print('file removed: ', file_to_delete)
            result = True

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Error. File not found.")
            file_to_delete = input('Please enter valid filename: ')
            
    return result
```

Comment: Okay, but I also wanted to include a prompt that specifically asks the user to enter a "valid" filename if they enters an invalid one.

Comment: That's better. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = False
while result == False:
    if result == True: break
    input("Please enter a valid filename: ")
```

The loop doesn't contain anything that would change the value of `result`, so yes, this loop will run forever.

Also, the call to `input()` is useless because you're not saving the result anywhere.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you think about that logic?

```
import os

def delete_file(file_to_delete):
    while not os.path.isfile(file_to_delete):
        print("Error. File not found.")
        file_to_delete = input("Please enter a valid filename: ")
    
    os.remove(file_to_delete)
    print('file removed: ', file_to_delete)
    return True
```